# Sending stock alert emails using google apps script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to setup a simple google apps script to send emails when inventory on various components hits the defined threshold. After reading and searching I put together a script that appears to work but starts to send erroneous emails when I increase the range being pulled from my spreadsheet.

Here's my code and further details are below.

```js
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("Inventory Report");
var howFar = 5 //sheet.getMaxRows(); // how many rows of data
var onHand = sheet.getRange(2,14,howFar,1).getValues();
var minimum = sheet.getRange(2,16,howFar,1).getValues();
var itemNum = sheet.getRange(2,1,howFar,1).getValues();
var itemName = sheet.getRange(2,2,howFar,1).getValues();

var sendTo = "test@gmail.com";
var overStock = 1.5;  // warning factor over minimum

function stockAlert() {
  for (var i = 0; i < onHand.length; i++) { 
    if (onHand[i] < minimum[i] * overStock && onHand[i] > minimum[i]) {
        MailApp.sendEmail( sendTo , "Testing Stock Reorder Notifications", itemNum[i] + " " + itemName[i] +" - Stock is low! Current stock is " + onHand[i] + ". Minimum is " + minimum[i] + ".");
    }
    else if (minimum[i] > 0 && onHand[i] < minimum[i]) {
        MailApp.sendEmail( sendTo , "Testing Stock Cirtical Notifications", itemNum[i] + " " + itemName[i] +" - Stock is Critical and will be depleted! Current stock is " + onHand[i] + ". Minimum is " + minimum[i] + ".");
    } 
  }
}
```

In my sheet the values for minimum are 200, 400, 200, 300, 600
In my sheet the values for onHand are 270, 270, 920, 920, 1830

This means I should see one low stock email for the first set of values, one critical stock email for the second set of values and no emails for the last 3 sets of values.

If `var howfar = 3`, the script sends the two appropriate emails.
If `var howfar = 5`, I get a third critical stock email for the fifth set of values that should not be sent. Interestingly the email body shows that it's referencing the correct set of values but `else if` should be false.

The body of the incorrect email reads:

> `itemNum` `itemName` - Stock is Critical and will be depleted! Current stock is 1830. Minimum is 600.

Given my extensive background in not coding, I hope and assume this will be a simple fix, but any all help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: can you share a test spreadsheet if you want I'll see your case with you on the chat of the spreadsheet.

Comment: btw your code looks just fine, it's really weird

Comment: @JSmith I setup a test sheet. I just pasted the resulting values from my original sheet. I get the same results when testing the script. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1p0ElAjSvwvZtzDKOO0PrZBnzDuVIjxpilXOa8qEgmMU/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any chance the values are treated as text in the spreadsheet? Note that the string `"1830"` is indeed `<` the string `"600"`. If they are text in the spreadsheet (rather than numbers), then when Apps Script reads the values in, they will be kept as `String`s.

edit: indeed, this is the source of your issue - you compare 2D arrays at the `Array` level:

```
Logger.log(minimum[i]); // "[600.0]"
Logger.log(typeof minimum[i]); // object

Logger.log(minimum[i][0]); // 600.0
Logger.log(typeof minimum[i][0]); // number
```

The simplest fix is then to simply access the desired element of the 2D array. Since you acquired only single columns, there is only 1 element in each inner array (at index 0). Thus, `<array>[i][0]` instead of `<array>[i]`.

An extension to this, which will work for situations in which the sheet values may be text, is to explicitly cast to a number before comparing by using the JS function [`parseInt(val, radix)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt). Assuming `minimum` and others are 2D arrays as they are in your question code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < onHand.length; i++) {
  var min = parseInt(minimum[i][0], 10),
      avail = parseInt(onHand[i][0], 10);
  if (avail < min) {
    // send critical stock email
  }
  else if (avail < min * overStock) {
    // send reorder email
  }
  else {
    // on hand amount is > needed
  }
}
```

For a blank string, e.g. `parseInt("", 10)`, or other non-numeric inputs the return value is the number `NaN` which is neither `>` or `<` than actual numbers, so bad inputs should not result in an email being sent.

---

A different issue is that your script populates global variables with interface calls, which results in slower execution of *any* script. A better approach is to wrap the related setup in a function:

```
function getStockAmounts() {
  // Return an object of the inventory values.
  const stock = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("some name");
  const numHeaders = 1,
        numVals = stock.getLastRow() - numHeaders;
  return [
    {p: 'minimum', col: 16},
    {p: 'onHand', col: 14},
    {p: 'itemName', col: 2},
    {p: 'itemNum', col: 1}
  ].reduce(function (obj, key) {
    obj[key.p] = stock.getRange(numHeaders + 1, key.col, numVals, 1)
      .getValues()
      // Return a 1-D array, rather than a 2-D array, since all these are single-column variables.
      .map(function (row) { return row[0]; });
    return obj;
  }, {'numVals': numVals});
}
```

and then call this from your script:

```
function foo() {
  const stocks = getStockAmounts();
  for (var i = 0; i < stocks.numVals; i++) {
    var min = stocks.minimum[i]; // 1D arrays, so only 1 index is needed.
    ...
```

- [`Range#getValues()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [`Array#reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce)

Comment: well done should have though about it before. he can also use `Number(string)`function

Comment: `onHand` was already defined so I used `onH` and it worked. Thanks!

Comment: @MicahRoth whoops, missed that. Note that there was a fundamental issue in array comparison vs element comparison - `getValues` returns a "2-D" array, not a 1D array.

Comment: @tehhowch Thanks for the additional information! Soooo much to learn